# No puedo mostrar los datos del objeto que envio al componente Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

cree un componente de prueba para poder importarlo a una vista en Vuejs y enviarle los datos que leo de mockapi. Cuando llamo al componente en la vista uso el v-for y le paso el objecto, pero no puedo cargarlo en el v-card. No se que estoy haciendo mal o si me esta faltando algun paso. Podrian darme una mano?

src\components\Listado.vue

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto ma-4" max-width="300">
    <v-img class="white--text align-end" height="200px">
      <v-card-title>{{ objproducto.name }}</v-card-title>
    </v-img>

    <v-card-subtitle class="pb-0"> ${{ objproducto.costo }} </v-card-subtitle>

    <v-card-text class="text--primary">
      <div>{{ objproducto.descripcion }}</div>
    </v-card-text>

    <v-card-actions>
 </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
      
    };
  },
  
  props:{
    objproducto: Object
    
  },

  methods:{
    consulta(){
      console.log("Esto deberia ser ",this.objproducto)
    }
  }
};
```

src\views\ProductList.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <Listado v-for="producto in productos" :key="producto.id"
          :objproducto="productos" />
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Listado from "../components/Listado.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        productos: Object
   };
  },
 
  components: { Listado },
  mounted() {
    this.obtenerProductos();
  },

  methods: {
    obtenerProductos() {
      axios
        .get("https://61bwqdasdddsa359.mockapi.io/productos")
        .then((data) => {
          this.productos = data.data;
          console.log("Esto es de la vista",this.productos);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías o de borradores de diseño para probar el diseño visual antes de insertar el texto final

Comment: el comentario sobre el lorem ipsum se agradece, pero en que tiene que ver con tu pregunta? ejjeje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Listado v-for="producto in productos" :key="producto.id"
          :objproducto="productos" />
```

Aqui estas pasando como `objproducto` el array de `productos`, en su lugar debes pasar un solo `producto`, resultando asi:

```
<Listado v-for="producto in productos" :key="producto.id"
          :objproducto="producto" />
```

Esto es asi ya que el `v-for` repite el componente `Listado` por cuantos `producto` existan en `productos` y en el componente `Listado` estas esperando el `producto`, no todos los `productos`.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Algo tan sencillo como eso. Muchas gracias estaba quemado

Comment: por nada, sigue aprendiendo que VueJs esta bueno. Saludos